# C - Can't get the number of lines in text file? Are there other ways to get?

Tags: c, file-io

I want program count lines in text file by function. It used to work ,but it always return 0 now.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int couLineF(FILE* fp){ //count lines in file
    int count = 0,ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(ch == (int)"\n" ) count++;
    }
    rewind(fp);
    return count;
}

int main(){

     FILE *fp = fopen("book.txt","r");
    int lines;
        if(fp){
            lines = couLineF(fp);
            printf("number of lines is : %d",lines);

        }

        return 0;

}
```

---

### Another question

Are there any other ways to get number of lines in text file?

Comment: GCC (and likely other compilers) give a warning on this line `cast from pointer to integer of different size`, theres a hint you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(ch == (int)"\n" )
```

You are casting the address of `"\n"`, a string literal, into an `int` and comparing it with `ch`. This doesn't make any sense.

Replace it with

```
if(ch == '\n' )
```

to fix it. This checks if `ch` is a newline character.(Use single quotes(`'`) for denoting a character and double quotes(`"`) for a string)

---

Other problems are:

- Not closing the file using `fclose` if `fopen` was successful.
- Your program won't count the last line if it doesn't end with `\n`.
- There is absolutely no reason to use `rewind(fp)` as you never use the `FILE` pointer again.

Comment: But `ch` is an `int` type variable. How that will be compared to a string/character literal?

Comment: Character literals have their own integer values as represented in the [ASCII table](http://benborowiec.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/better_ascii_table.jpg).

Comment: @PrerakSola: in C there is no type called "string/character literal". A 'character literal' is just another number, and "string" is no C type.